# Post XML to Server in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am working on a vb.net application which need SMS functioning into application. 
SMS service provider [API](http://api.msg91.com/apidoc/textsms/xml-send-sms.php#xmlcontent) asked to use XML API to send large number of message. Also using XML API we can customize different message for each number.

```xml
Sample XML format as per SMS Provider:
<MESSAGE>
    <AUTHKEY>Authentication Key </AUTHKEY>
    <SENDER>SenderID</SENDER>
    <ROUTE>Template</ROUTE>
    <CAMPAIGN>XML API</CAMPAIGN>
    <COUNTRY>country code</COUNTRY>
    <SMS TEXT="message1" >
        <ADDRESS TO="number1"></ADDRESS>
    </SMS>
    <SMS TEXT="hi test message" >
        <ADDRESS TO="number2"></ADDRESS>
    </SMS>
</MESSAGE>
Post your request with above format in data variable.
http://api.msg91.com/api/postsms.php
```

Provider dnt have any sample code for VB.NET So after lot of search finally got some info on using HttpWebRequest in VB. 
& Put up code but its outputting "Code:201"

```
Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Data.OleDb
    Imports System.Globalization
    Imports System.Text
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Net
    Imports System.Web
    Imports System.Xml

    Dim authKey As String
    Dim mobile As String
    Dim senderId As String
    Dim route As String
    Dim URLXML As String = "http://api.msg91.com/api/postsms.php?data="

       'Set these variables
        authKey = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
        mobile = String.Empty
        'Sender ID, While using route4 sender id should be 6 characters long.
        senderId = "XXXXXX"
        'Define route
        route = "X"

    Private Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
        If (DataGridView2.Rows.Count > 0) Then
            Dim xml As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
            xml.Append("<MESSAGE>" & Environment.NewLine)
            xml.Append("<AUTHKEY>" & authKey & "</AUTHKEY>" & Environment.NewLine)
            xml.Append("<SENDER>" & senderId.ToString & "</SENDER>" & Environment.NewLine)
            xml.Append("<ROUTE>" & route.ToString & "</ROUTE>" & Environment.NewLine)
            xml.Append("<COUNTRY>91</COUNTRY>" & Environment.NewLine)

            'MOBILE & MESSAGE FIELDS LOADED FROM DATAGRIDVIEW ROWS
            For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
                    xml.Append("<SMS TEXT='" & URLEncode(DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("MESSAGE").Value.ToString) & "'>" & Environment.NewLine)
                    xml.Append("<ADDRESS TO='" & DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("MOBILE").Value.ToString & "'></ADDRESS>")
                    xml.Append("</SMS>" & Environment.NewLine)
            Next
            xml.Append("</MESSAGE>")

            'URLEncode Whole input String as told by the SMS Provider 
            Dim xmlData As String = URLEncode(xml.ToString)
            ' Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
            Dim bytes As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(xmlData)

            Try 
                Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(URLXML), HttpWebRequest)
                req.Method = "POST"
                ' Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                ' Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
                req.ContentLength = bytes.Length
                ' Get the request stream.
                Using dataStream As Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
                    dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
                End Using


                ' Get the response.
                'Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
                Dim response As HttpWebResponse = req.GetResponse()
                If (response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK) Then
                    ' Display the status.
                    ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
                    Dim dStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                    ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dStream, True)
                    ' Read the content
                    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
                    ' Display the content.
                    MsgBox(responseFromServer.ToString)
                    reader.Close()
                    dStream.Close()
                End If
                ' Clean up & close
                response.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

Public Function URLEncode(ByVal Text As String) As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim acode As Integer
        'Dim chars As String
        URLEncode = Text
        For i = Len(URLEncode) To 1 Step -1
            acode = Asc(Mid$(URLEncode, i, 1))
            Select Case acode
                Case 10
                    'replace line break to "0A"
                    Mid$(URLEncode, i, 1) = "0A"
                Case 47 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122
                    ' don't touch alphanumeric chars
                Case 32
                    ' replace space with "+"
                    Mid$(URLEncode, i, 1) = "+"
                Case Else
                    ' replace punctuation chars with "%hex"
                    URLEncode = Left$(URLEncode, i - 1) & "%" & Hex$(acode) & Mid$ _
                        (URLEncode, i + 1)
            End Select
        Next
End Function
```

On 1st Run Error message appears :

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote  name could not be resolved": 'api.msg91.com' at System.Net.http.WebRequest.GetRequestStream
```

& second time output is Code:201
1 Error message also appears in immediate window "A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll".

Since SMS provider dnt have any Code Sample for VB.NET they sent me this [link](https://textgoto.com/xml-api-sample-code-vb). Then i made some changes as per the code:

1) NO URLENCODE on Whole XML String
2) Changed content type: text/plain
3) Added req.timeout
4) Used StreamWriter instead of stream.

```
Dim req As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URLXML)
        req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post
        ' Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        'req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        req.ContentType = "text/plain"
        ' Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        req.ContentLength = xml.Length
        req.Timeout = 1000000
        ' Get the request stream.
        Dim sw As New StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream)
        sw.Write(xml.ToString)
        sw.Close()
```

With this code no WebException or immmediate window error, but got same output Code:201.
As per documentation. Output should be: 5134842646923e183d000075. 
Output will be request ID which is alphanumeric and contains 24 characters like mentioned above. With this request ID, delivery Report can be viewed. If request not sent sucessfully, you will get the appropriate error message

The [other method](http://api.msg91.com/apidoc/textsms/send-sms.php#sendcontent) of provider for sending the same text message to all users is working but it takes lot of time to run the code using loop, if we have to send large number of requests then XML API should be used . Unable to understand the reason why XML method is not posting data. Whats the error or mistake in the code, pls help/guide me to correct. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Also try to change content type property & ASCIIEncoding but same output:

```
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success 201 = "The request has been fulfilled, resulting in the creation of a new resource"

Comment: Yes but data not posted. As per documentation. Output should be: 5134842646923e183d000075
Note : Output will be request ID which is alphanumeric and contains 24 characters like mentioned above. With this request ID, delivery Report can be viewed. If request not sent sucessfully, you will get the appropriate error message

Answer (score 2):

I just used msg91 service after a day long of trying with the same issue I got Succesful by the following code

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ' Create a request using a URL that can receive a post.   
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://sms.orreryhim.com/api/postsms.php")
        ' Set the Method property of the request to POST.  
        request.Method = "POST"
        ' Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.  
        Dim postData As String = "<MESSAGE>
    <AUTHKEY>your authkey here</AUTHKEY>
    <ROUTE>route code</ROUTE>
    <CAMPAIGN>campaign mode</CAMPAIGN>
    <COUNTRY>country code</COUNTRY>
    <SENDER>sender id</SENDER>
    <SMS TEXT='"messges'">
        <ADDRESS TO="'mobile number'"></ADDRESS>
    </SMS>
</MESSAGE>"
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
        ' Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.  
        request.ContentType = "application/xml"
        ' Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.  
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        ' Get the request stream.  
        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        ' Write the data to the request stream.  
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        ' Close the Stream object.  
        dataStream.Close()
        ' Get the response.  
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        ' Display the status.  
        'Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
        Label1.Text = CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription
        ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.  
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
        ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        ' Read the content.  
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        ' Display the content.  
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
        Label2.Text = responseFromServer
        ' Clean up the streams.  
        reader.Close()
        dataStream.Close()
        response.Close()


    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! In order to provide a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please consider elaborating your findings. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.